# How can I find out the actual path to an EXE or BAT file?

Tags: path, batch-file

If I have a long and involved PATH and I type the name of some command, how do I find out where the EXE or BAT file actually lives.  I thought TRUENAME did this but it's gone from XP and I'm not sure it did exactly what I want.

So I want to be able to type

```
WHEREIS "Obscure Tool.exe"
```

and I get:

```
C:\Program Files\Obscure Tools Limited\Obscure Tool\Obscure Tool.exe
```

when the folder `C:\Program Files\Obscure Tools Limited\Obscure Tool\` is on my path.  What is WHEREIS called, or can it be done with a batch file?

Comment: `truename` does something else.

Comment: See [Is there an equivalent of 'which' on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/304447)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a windows batch file that will search your path for a file.  I have tested it on XP and Win7.

Please understand that a batch/command file is NOT a good solution to this problem because string manipulation is painfully slow - but in lieu of a compiled tool, this will do what you desire.

Hopefully it is commented well enough, but feel free to ask questions if anything needs clarification.

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem -- SRC = Search value. Eg. notepad  or  notepad.exe
rem -- PAT = A copy of the path
rem -- SEP = PATH seperator
rem -- EXE = Executable file extensions
SET TMP_SRC=%1
SET TMP_PAT=%PATH%
SET TMP_SEP=;
SET TMP_EXE=exe com bat cmd

rem -- This is a batch file ...they are s-l-o-w
rem -- "<nul set /p=" does "echo" without a newline
<nul set /p =Searching...

:strLoop
    rem -- SUB = The first entry in the current PATH
    for /f "delims=%TMP_SEP%" %%s in ("!TMP_PAT!") do set TMP_SUB=%%s

    rem -- Progress update
    <nul set /p =.

    rem -- Check for the file exactly as specified on the command line
    if exist "!TMP_SUB!\%TMP_SRC%" (
        echo.
        echo Found "!TMP_SUB!\%TMP_SRC%"
        goto strDone
    )

    rem -- Check for the file with each of the selected executable extensions
    for %%x in (%TMP_EXE%) do (
        if exist "!TMP_SUB!\%TMP_SRC%.%%x" (
            echo.
            echo Found "!TMP_SUB!\%TMP_SRC%.%%x"
            goto strDone
        )
    )

    rem -- This loop chops off the first entry of the PATH
:subLoop
    rem -- CHR = First character of current PATH
    rem -- PAT -> All but the first character of the current PATH
    set TMP_CHR=!TMP_PAT:~0,1!
    set TMP_PAT=!TMP_PAT:~1!

    rem -- Have we exhausted the PATH?
    if "!TMP_PAT!" EQU "" goto strDone

    rem -- Have we just removed a PATH seperator?
    if "!TMP_CHR!" EQU "%TMP_SEP%" goto strLoop

    rem -- Keep stripping characters
    goto subLoop
:strDone

rem -- Cleanup
SET TMP_SRC=
SET TMP_PAT=
SET TMP_SEP=
SET TMP_SUB=
SET TMP_CHR=
SET TMP_EXE=

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: +1 for effort (and for the tip about echoing text without a `CR`).  I haven't looked it over to see _how_ it works, but I have tried it and it only takes a few seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends from what command interpreter one is running, and there isn't an external utility that is going to do this properly in all cases.  This is for a very imporant reason:

> **Different command interpreters look for commands in different ways.**

Only a command built in to each individual command interpreter will truly know what will be invoked by a particular command name.

- **For [JP Software's TCC](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html)**, simply use [its built-in `which` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/which.htm).  This understands TCC's aliases, executable extensions, and path search algorithm.

  ```
  [c:\]which mspaint dir
  mspaint is an external : C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe
  dir is an internal command
  [c:\]
  ```
- **For the Korn shell, `ksh`,** as available in the [SFUA utility toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=93FF2201-325E-487F-A398-EFDE5758C47F) (which run in the [Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772343.aspx) that comes right there in the box with Windows 7 Ultimate edition and Windows Server 2008 R2) use [its built-in `whence` command](http://mkssoftware.com./docs/man1/whence.1.asp).  This understands the Korn shell's aliases, functions, built-in commands, and so forth.

  ```
  $ whence -v ls
  ls is a tracked alias for /bin/ls
  $
  ```
- **For the Bourne-Again shell, `bash`,** as [available for Services for Unix Applications](http://suacommunity.com./tool_warehouse.aspx) as well as in Cygwin, use its built-in `type` command.  This understands the Boune-Again shell's aliases, functions, built-in commands, and so forth.

  ```
  $ type '['
  [ is a shell builtin
  $
  ```
- **For Microsoft's command interpreter, `cmd`,** you're out of luck.  There's no built-in command for doing this; and although one can employ *external* commands that will replicate the path search algorithm, those commands will not necessarily (or even usually) recognize aliases and built-in commands.  For examples:  Here is the GnuWin32 `which` command *failing* to recognize `dir` (in contrast with TCC's built-in `which` command above):

  ```
  C:\>which dir
  which: no dir in (.;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem)
  C:\>
  ```

  And here is the `where` command mentioned by `grawity` below failing in exactly the same fashion:

  ```
  C:\>where dir
  INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
  C:\>
  ```

Comment: Recent Windows versions come with a tool named `where` (which is still an external command, though).

Comment: I wouldn't say "where" is failing; its spec is to search the current directory then the PATH for *files* matching the search pattern, not commands. It should be available from Vista and above.

Answer (score 4):

If you have [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) it's as simple as:

```
which ObscureTool.exe
```

Even better, if you're invoking it by name only (without an extension, as in "ObscureTool"), it'll still find the right thing. This might be an issue if you have *two* "executable" files: "ObscureTool.exe" and "ObscureTool.bat". In this case, **WHICH** will find the one that occurs *first* in the path. In this case, you'd merely say"

```
which ObscureTool
```

Answer (score 4):

I am running regular Windows 7 and simply typing "where java.exe" seems to work great without any additional software.

Answer (score 3):

Using powershell you can use the `Get-Command tool.exe`

Answer (score 2):

You could use 'dir', the directory listing tool:

```
dir "c:\Obscure Tool.exe" /s/b
```

The /s means search subdirectories, and since you are starting in the root folder (C:) it will search all the folders on that drive.
The /b makes it display the result in "bare" format with no heading information or summary (ie. you will just get the path and filename).

Comment: +1 This is my favorite brute-force search method, if Windows' GUI search tools fail me for whatever reason (though since Vista, they've gotten better, in my opinion).

Comment: this will list ALL files called Obscure Tool.  Not the one in the path.

Comment: Everything.exe is always faster than a normal search through lots of directories. It does it immediately. Though probably no command line option like output on command line.

Comment: And it won't find files that are in the path but on another drive.